# Python Variables across Class functions - how to call them?

Tags: python, class

Instead of using a global variable, I'm trying to make an instance of a variable in a class, as it seems to be best practice. How do I reference this variable across other functions in the class?  I would have thought that `Test.running_sum` would work or at least `running_sum` in `test_function`, but I'm not having any luck with either. Thanks very much!

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        running_sum = 0

    def test_function(self):
        print(Test.running_sum)
        return

    x = Test()
    x.test_function()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Test:
  File "so.py", line 10, in Test
    x = Test()
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

Comment: `running_sum` is an attribute of an instance of the class `Test`. You can't call it on the class itself like you're doing `Test.running_sum`. Other problem I see. Why is `test_function` outside of the `Test` class? it doesnt make sense

Comment: The indentation in that code is wrong. `x = Test()` and `x.test_function()` need to be de-indented so they aren't inside the class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `self` parameter provided in the method signature.

Note that what you wrote is not a method, but an external function using class `Test`. To write a method of `Test`, the `def` should be at one level of indentation inside `class Test` as following:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running_sum = 0
    def test_function(self):
        print(self.running_sum)
```

---

There are several things to add if you want an explanation behind this "best practice".

Assuming you write the following code:

```
class Test:
    numbers = []
    def add(self, value):
        self.numbers.append(value)
```

The `Test.numbers` list is instantiated once and shared accross all instances of `Test`. Therefore, if 2 different instances add to the list, both act on the same list:

```
a = Test()
b = Test()
a.add(5)
b.add(10)
assert a.numbers == b.numbers == Test.numbers
```

When creating instance variables in the `__init__` function, `__init__` will be run at each instantiation, and therefore, the list will no longer be shared because they will be created for each individual instances.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = []
    def add(self, number):
        self.numbers.append(number)

a = Test()
b = Test()
a.add(5)
b.add(10)
assert a != b
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an object attribute: each object gets its own.
`Test` is the class; `self` is the `Test` object that invoked the method.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.running_sum = 0

    def test_function(self):
        self.running_sum += 1
        print(self.running_sum)
        return

x = Test()
y = Test()
x.test_function()
y.test_function()
```

Output:
    1
    1

As a class attribute: all objects share the same variable.
`self.__class__` is the class of the invoking object (i.e. `Test`).

```
class Test:
    running_sum = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def test_function(self):
        self.__class__.running_sum += 1
        print(self.__class__.running_sum)
        return

x = Test()
y = Test()
x.test_function()
y.test_function()
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do I reference this variable across other functions in the class

Several things I see wrong here. First of all, you are calling `running_sum` on the class itself which doesn't make sense since you are declaring `running_sum` as an attribute of an instance of `Test`. Second, from the way you formatted your question, it seems that `test_function` is outside of the class `Test` which doesn't make sense since you are passing `self` to it, implying it is an instance method. To resolve you could do this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running_sum = 0
    def test_function(self):
        print(self.running_sum)
```

Then again this also is weird... Why would you need a "test_function" when you can simply test the value of `running_sum` by simply doing:

```
x = Test()
x.running_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__` function, you've created a `local variable.` That variable will no longer exist after the function has completed.

If you want to create a variable specific to the **object** `x` then you should create a `self.running_sum` variable

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.running_sum = 0

    def test_function(self):
        print(self.running_sum)
```

If you want to create a variable specific to the **class** `Test` then you should create a `Test.running_sum` variable.

```
class Test:
    running_sum = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def test_function(self):
        print(Test.running_sum)
```

Comment: Much better. :) I guess you could also get rid of those redundant `return` statements.